# SQLITE create table syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1])

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, create-table

I need some help, I have this query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staff_ratio
(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, type INTEGER CHECK ( type IN (0, 1) ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
shift INTEGER CHECK ( shift IN (0, 2, 1)) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
personal_count INTEGER, clients INTEGER, ratio REAL, date INTEGER NOT NULL, restaurant_id INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurants(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
hotel_staff_ratio_id INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(hotel_staff_ratio_id) REFERENCES hotel_staff_ratio(id) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "hotel_staff_ratio_id": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1])
```

Comment: You seem to have a closing )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up column specifications and table constraints.

Columns specifications such as `hotel_staff_ratio_id INTEGER NOT NULL` come first and table constraints such as `FOREIGN KEY(restaurant_id) REFERENCES restaurants(id) ON DELETE CASCADE` go last.

Move the `hotel_staff_ratio_id INTEGER NOT NULL` before the first `FOREIGN KEY` table constraint.